# How to make C3.js charts height Dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, c3.js

I'm using C3.js and when I have a lot of data, the chart doesn't render quite well and it's because of its height. C3 somehow is setting a fixed height and it's only showing the bottom labels. I tried using the legend: `{show: false}` property but it doesn't solve my  issue correctly.

This is what it looks like:
[image]

The code from where I put the chart :

```html
<div id="chart_product" class="section-to-print"> </div>
```

And the CSS:

```css
.section-to-print, .section-to-print * {
   visibility: visible;
}

.section-to-print {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
}
```

Finally, when I inspect the DOM it sets the div like this:

[image: Image DOM]

I would really appreciate all your help. Thank you!

Answer (score -3):

```
<div style='width:1000px;height:300px;'>
    <div id="chart_product" class="section-to-print"> </div>
</div>
```

**Please enclose the chart div with another div and you can change the width and height dynamically.**